# error: no match for call when calling a function by a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

i'm trying to make the producer/consumer design in c++ but actually i'm stuck.
i'm getting this error

> error: no match for call to
>
> ‘(std::thread) (void (&)())’  prods[i]>(producer,i);

when i call the producer function from a loop
here is my main:

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 
 std::thread prods[argv[1]];
  for (int i = 0; i <= argc;i++){
    prods[i](producer,i);
    } 

  return 0;
 }
```

and here my producer function

```
  void producer(int i){
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
  std::cout << "(1) produit 20";
  jobs.push(20);
  notified = true;
  cond_var.notify_one();
  done = true;
  
  }
```

has someone an idea how to solve that ? thanks in advance.

Comment: i just edited the post the number of producer threads will be given as main argument

Comment: `std::thread prods[argv[1]];` is not standard C++ (VLAs are a compiler extension) and you cannot use a `char*` as a size either. Use a `std::vector<std::thread>`

Comment: same error : no match call 
   
  to:  `‘(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::thread> >::value_type {aka std::thread}) (void (&)())’ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads aren't callable, you need to explicitly call the thread constructor to create a thread:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const size_t n = 4;
    std::vector< std::thread > prods( n );
    for (int i = 0; i <= n;i++)
    {
        prods[i] = std::thread(producer,i);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I've also replaced the non-standard variable length array with a `std::vector` and hard coded the thread count as your handling of command line arguments was also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.  The first is that

```
std::thread prods[argv[1]];
```

is non standard.  It is a variable length array (VLA) and is not part of the C++ standard.  If you want an array but won't know its size until run-time then you should use a `std::vector`.

Your second issue is that

```
prods[i](producer,i);
```

is not how you would assign a thread to each element of the array.  What you arr syntactically tryin to do is call the fucntion call operator (`operator ()`) on each thread in the array.  What you need is

```
prods[i] = std::thread(producer,i);
```

which will actually assign a thread to each array element.

The last issue is that

```
argv[1]
```

cannot be used as the size of the array/container as it is a `char*`.  If it holds the number of threads to create you need to convert it to a number with something like `std::stoi`.

That said, since you should be using a `std::vecotr`, you actual code should become something like

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::thread> prods;
    prods.reserve(size_you_want)
    for (int i = 0; i < size_you_want; i++){
        prods.push_back(std::thread(producer,i));
    } 
}
```